# Is an empty class an abstract class?

Tags: java, oop

I have an empty class (without attributes and methods), declared without the keyword "abstract" but It has a child class. Is it an abstract class or just a simple parent class.

```
public class Vehicle{
}
```

Comment: No.  It is not an abstract class.

Comment: "abstract" keyword is mandatory for a class to be abstract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go even further in the "emptiness" and create `new Object()`. But neither Object, nor your Vehicle are actually empty - they have methods like `equals()`, `toString()`, etc. And even if they were actually empty - they still wouldn't be abstract just because of their emptiness.

Abstract Classes are simply weird interfaces. Interfaces define some public API, same as Abstract Classes. And then every implementation must... well, implement that API. Does an empty class define an API? Nope. So it would be weird to consider such classes abstract.

Note, that in modern OOP inheritance is mostly considered a bad practice (look up *Inheritance vs. Composition*). Therefore by definition abstract classes would be considered a bad idea by many.

Answer (score 0):

The `Vehicle` is not an abstract class, because you can instantiation its as opposed to an abstract class (write `new Vehicle()` without additional definitions).

Answer (score 0):

No, an empty class without abstract keyword is not an abstract class.

You need to write `abstract` during declaring a class to make it abstract.

E.g

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

}
```

This is a good resource for a quick read:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html